# How come the righteous Servant gets to see "His seed" even when he has no generations? Is 53:8,10

Tags: word-study, contradiction, isaiah, messiah

> Isaiah 53:8(NKJV)
>
> He was taken from prison and from judgment, **And who
>   will declare His generation**? For He was cut off from the land of the
>   living; For the transgressions of My people He was stricken.   Yet it
>   pleased the LORD to bruise Him; He has put Him to grief. When You make
>   His soul an offering for sin, **He shall see His seed**, He shall
>   prolong His days, And the pleasure of the LORD shall prosper in His
>   hand.

So I wonder:

1) How does he get to see his seed when he would be cut off from the earth without generations or descendants.

2) What exactly is his Seed?

Comment: He gets cut off, then his days get prolonged while seeing his seed. It's a prophecy of the ressurection.

Answer (score 3):

The pronouns may be confusing you.  Both pronouns in "He shall see His seed" are Jehova. "His seed" are all who are born again of the water and the spirit (John 3:5) who are in Christ; they become God's spiritual children.  Look at it in the YLT version.

> "10 And Jehovah hath delighted to bruise him, He hath made him sick, If his soul doth make an offering for guilt, **He seeth seed** -- he prolongeth days, And the pleasure of Jehovah in his hand doth prosper.
>
> 11 Of the labour of his soul he seeth -- he is satisfied, Through his knowledge give righteousness **Doth the righteous one, My servant, to many,** And their iniquities he doth bear."

Christ bore all of our sins in His death on the cross, thereby allowing all who will believe, repent, and be baptized into Christ to have remission of sins, and we are then counted for the seed of Abraham.

Gal. 3:26-29.

> "26 **for ye are all sons of God through the faith in Christ Jesus**,
>
> 27 for as many as to Christ were baptized did put on Christ;
>
> 28 there is not here Jew or Greek, there is not here servant nor freeman, there is not here male and female, for all ye are one in Christ Jesus;
>
> 29 **and if ye [are] of Christ then of Abraham ye are seed,** and according to promise -- heirs."  (YLT)

When we are in Christ, God sees Christ's sacrifice covering us. And as counted for the seed of Abraham we become the Israel that is saved with an everlasting salvation.

Isa. 45:17,

> "But Israel shall be **saved in the Lord with an everlasting salvation:** ye shall not be ashamed nor confounded world without end."  (KJV)

Those who are in Christ are "His seed", the children of God.

(Bold emphasis is mine.)

Answer (score 2):

### 1) How does he get to see his seed when he would be cut off from the earth without generations or descendants?

The victorious and triumphant end to the trial of this Servant (cf. *Ps 22b*) is only explicable if He obtains some resurrection from the dead ("cut off from the land of the living ... [himself made] an offering for sin"), which we in fact find toward the end ("he shall prolong his days [i.e. his life] ... the pleasure of the LORD shall prosper in his hand") (cf. *Ps 16:10*).

### 2) What is His seed?

"Seed" can refer to literal *offspring*, such as:

> **2 Samuel 7:12 (DRB)**
>
> And when thy days shall be fulfilled, and thou shalt sleep with thy fathers, I will raise up thy *seed* after thee, *which shall proceed out of thy bowels*, and I will establish his kingdom.

But also figurative, as in the *followers* of Jesus Christ:

> **Revelation 12:17 (DRB) (cf. 12:1,5)**
>
> And the dragon was angry with the woman, and went to make war with *the remnant of her seed*, **who keep the commandments of God, and have the testimony of Jesus.**

cf. *Gn 3:15; Rom 16:20*.

Given this meaning of 'follower,' Christ's 'seed' are *His brethren according to faith*: His disciples (*Jn 19:26-27; Mt 12:48-49; Heb 2:11*).

Answer (score 1):

The two previous answers are good ones. If you're still having trouble with the seed being counted as a generation, here are a couple more verses that may help.

Psalm 22: 30 (KJV)

"A seed shall serve him; it shall be accounted to the Lord for a generation."

Romans 9:8 (KJV)

"…They which are the children of the flesh, these are not the children of God: but the children of the promise are counted for the seed."

All those who have faith in Christ are heirs according to the promise to Abraham and are counted as part of the seed (descending generation) of Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 0):

10 And now I say unto you, who shall declare his generation? Behold, I say unto you, that when his soul has been made an offering for sin he shall see his seed. And now what say ye? And who shall be his seed?
11 Behold I say unto you, that whosoever has heard the words of the prophets, yea, all the holy prophets who have prophesied concerning the coming of the Lord—I say unto you, that all those who have hearkened unto their words, and believed that the Lord would redeem his people, and have looked forward to that day for a remission of their sins, I say unto you, that these are his seed, or they are the heirs of the kingdom of God.
12 For these are they whose sins he has borne; these are they for whom he has died, to redeem them from their transgressions. And now, are they not his seed?
13 Yea, and are not the prophets, every one that has opened his mouth to prophesy, that has not fallen into transgression, I mean all the holy prophets ever since the world began? I say unto you that they are his seed.
14 And these are they who have published peace, who have brought good tidings of good, who have published salvation; and said unto Zion: Thy God reigneth!

15 And O how beautiful upon the mountains were their feet!
16 And again, how beautiful upon the mountains are the feet of those that are still publishing peace!
17 And again, how beautiful upon the mountains are the feet of those who shall hereafter publish peace, yea, from this time henceforth and forever!
18 And behold, I say unto you, this is not all. For O how beautiful upon the mountains are the feet of him that bringeth good tidings, that is the founder of peace, yea, even the Lord, who has redeemed his people; yea, him who has granted salvation unto his people;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Jesus days were prolonged because he was ressurected from death and a little while later ascended into heaven where he now lives forever eternally. Jesus christ is also the Lord God and father in heaven. Even the Lord who spoke to moses in the burning bush and on mt sinai. "Truly truly i say to you before abraham was IAM." (John 8:58 (in reference to exodus 3:13-15.) Jesus said "I and the father are one." (John 10:30) Jesus also said "if you have seen me you have seen the father." (John 14:7-9) We know isaiah said "the son and child shall be called the everlasting father and the mighty God." (Isaiah 9:6) John wrote "He was in the world and the world was made by him" (john 1:10)

So with all these things being considered jesus is the eternal father in heaven.

Galatians 3:26 we are all the children of God through faith in jesus christ. 27For as many of you as have been baptized into Christ have put on Christ. 28There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither bond nor free, there is neither male nor female: for ye are all one in Christ Jesus. 29And if ye be Christ's, then are ye Abraham's seed, and heirs according to the promise.

Jesus gave us power to become the sons of God to those who believe in his name John 1:12) with all this being said are we not then his seed? Are we not part of the same family being the sons/children of God and abrahams seed through faith and so heirs according to the promise?

So jesus days were prolonged and he shall see his seed. His seed are believers, the sons of God and heirs according to the promise.